# Excel: How to extract information on a table to another worksheet based on values in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7FYV.jpg)

What is the best way to create a workbook based on information on a table. I have a table 13 columns wide and 500 plus rows, in the 11th column is the name of who equipment belongs to. The name can occur many time in the column as they can own a few pieces of equipment. I want a worksheet (named "HUXTER") that has all the pieces of equipment own by a certain individual (HUXTER) and as a group (ALL). It also has to have all the information about that equipment. It would be nice to easily update the main table and have it auto populate corresponding worksheet. In the end each worksheet will be locked and saved as a .csv to be loaded onto that individuals equipment.

Any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX(Meters!$A$1:$A$500,SMALL(IF(Meters!$K$1:$K$500=$Z$1,ROW(Meters!$K$1:$K$24)),ROW()),1),"")       I have been able to do it using this, other than I cant get the ALL listings to show up. I know an OR function should do the trick but cant seem to make it work. FYI: Z1 has the worksheet name (and what I am looking for) and I have AA1 as ALL (what I would also like to populate the table with).

Comment: Solved with nested IF

Comment: @lime, great if you solved this.  Please consider posting an answer with your solution.  That will help others with a similar problem.